# php array asort problem

Tags: php, arrays

this is my array:

```
$myarr = array(
               4 => 3,
               2 => 9,
               7 => 8,
               1 => 1
              );
```

when i do :

```
asort($myarr);
```

$myarr becomes:

```
array( 
      1 => 1,
      2 => 9,
      4 => 3,
      7 => 8
     );
```

This is not how it is supposed to work,right? the values should be sorted and keys maintained, while the reverse is happening - just like ksort. What can the problem be?

Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: I think you dont give the right codes, ,nsted working pseudo code. Did you run these in your server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works fine to me : http://codepad.org/o6pZ8ess

result :

```
array(4) {
  [1]=>
  int(1)
  [4]=>
  int(3)
  [7]=>
  int(8)
  [2]=>
  int(9)
}
```

Comment: Pretty limited (can't open/write file and some functions are missing for security) but works well for little test like these ;)

Comment: In case it helps anyone else, I was inspecting my sorted array output in Firebug and that seems to sort arrays by index all by itself, so as I was testing my PHP sorting it appeared not to be working as I wanted but in fact it was and this became apparent when I used print_r() instead to view the array contents. I imagine this is a very useful feature for Firebug with the exception of when you're testing sorting routines!!

Answer (score 4):

Works fine for me, did you try:

```
asort($myarr, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is not possible and the accepted answer is incorrect. I dont believe you can have integer keys in non numeric order.